# AngularJS: open default mail application and populate to and subject via link

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to open a link using `ng-href` and as soon as I click on it, I need it to open an email address and populate its To, Subject and it's Body field. Can this be made possible?

I tried this,

```
<a ng-click=”sendMail($event)” href=”gmail.com” />

$scope.sendMail = function($event)
        {
            if($scope.showMailLink == true )
            {
                $event.preventDefault();
                window.location = $event.target.href;
                $window.open("mailto:veron@gmail.com?subject=hello&body=fggf_self");
            }
        };
```

This is what I've tried and it isn't actually  right. Is this a valid approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `location.href`:

```
location.href = "mailto:veron@gmail.com?subject=hello&body=fggf"
```

or target the current window:

```
$window.open("mailto:veron@gmail.com?subject=hello&body=fggf", '_self');
```

---

### - Example -

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <button ng-click="mailWithLocation()">
     Mail via location.href 
   </button>
   <button ng-click="mailWithWindowOpen()">
     Mail via $window.open() 
   </button>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS Application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.mailWithLocation = function () {
       location.href = "mailto:veron@gmail.com?subject=hello&body=fggf"
    }

    $scope.mailWithWindowOpen = function () {
       $window.open("mailto:veron@gmail.com?subject=hello&body=fggf", '_self');
    }
});
```

Comment: Really helpful!.

Comment: I know it was two years, but never too late than ever. Thank you @lin! It worked!